# When is the phrase, “Are you sitting down?” used, and what does it exactly mean?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, figures-of-speech

There was the following paragraph in the article titled “How Russia wants to undermine the U.S. election” in Time magazine (October 10):

> One day in June she (Arizona Secretary of state, Michele Reagan) was
>   in her backyard in Phoenix when she got a call from her chief of
>   staff. “**Are you sitting down?”** he asked. ---A group of hackers
>   known as Fancy Bear was trying to sell a user name and password that
>   belonged to someone in Arizona county election official’s office,
>   which holds the personal data of almost 4 million people “My reaction
>   was, well, this is like the worst thing that you want to hear,” Reagan
>   recalls.

In other source – motherjones.com. (October 8), the phrase, “Are you sitting down?” is rephrased as “Can you sit down?'”:

> Arizona Secretary of State Michele Reagan was in the backyard of her home last June when she got a call from her chief of staff. "The first words out of his mouth were, '**Can you sit down?**'" Reagan told Mother Jones. He then said that her office had been "contacted by the FBI, and it looks like there's a computer password and username that belongs to our database for sale on the dark web."
>   http://www.motherjones.com/politics/2016/10/state-election-hacks-undermine-voters-confidence

Are “Are you sitting down?” and “Can you sit down?” used to try somebody to brace for a shocking news, or calm down the other in advance?
What do they exactly mean? Are they very popular turn of phrases?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what they're for. They're based on the assumption that it is easier to receive bad or shocking news if you're sitting down, because you're less likely to faint or crumble in a heap from the shock and despair of this news. I don't think there's much truth to that, but the mental image is there.

Comment: Yes, that's it.  It's an introduction to bad news.  "Are you sitting down?  It means "be prepared for bad news".  It's a reference to asking someone to sit down in case they faint because of unexpected news.

Comment: Yeah, "Are you sitting down?" basically means "Are you ready for some shocking news?"  I've never heard "Can you sit down?" used in the same sense, though "You might want to sit down" is sometimes used.

Comment: It would be better to have answers in the Your Answer box.

Comment: I agree with @tchrist.

Comment: Honestly, for the level of difficulty, this question is better suited for ELL, but it's written and presented so well that it deserves to stay on EL&U. But I'm going to ask for its migration all the same.

Comment: Closely related: [Meaning of “You might want to sit down for this”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134059/meaning-of-you-might-want-to-sit-down-for-this). I don't agree we need to migrate this question.

Comment: @Centaurus - it's not always *bad* news; it could equally be used for unexpectedly good news. For example, I would easily imagine using this phrase if I was telling family members that I'd won the lottery.

Comment: I'm not convinced this question is about English. You can ask the same thing under the same circumstances in many other languages.

Comment: Because "This is going to knock you off your feet".

Comment: This phrase is an Americanism. At least, I've never heard it used in the UK or Europe.

Comment: @smci Well, I have.

Comment: @MrLister: in which country? Presumably not in the UK? And when?

Comment: I don't think it makes you less likely to faint, I think it gives you less distance to fall if you do (Presuming you are sitting on a couch or something).  Also I've never heard "Can you sit down", but "You might want to take a seat for this" and "You'll want to be seated for this" and a few other variations are almost as common as "Are you sitting down?"

Comment: @Mr Lister. We don't have the same or similar expression to "Are you sitting down? / Can you sit down?" with English connotaion in Japanese.  Actually the question was raised at our local English literature reading circle last  week where two dozen English enthusiasts got together. Everybody scratched heads on this phrase, and  none of them was sure of the meaning. (Shamefully I interpreted the phrase as the Chief of staff's condemnation to mean "Are you basking in the sun at this critical moment?" ) So I placed the question on behalf of the circle members for the clalification of the meaning.

Answer (score 34):

Yes, that's what it means: "be prepared for some **bad** or, paradoxically, **very good** news I'm about to break."  It's **an introduction** to the news someone is about to break **over the phone** and a reference to the possibility they may faint or have any sort of untoward symptom when they experience **intense surprise, fear or shock**. If one is sitting down, they are less likely to get hurt.

Examples of cases where you'd ask **"are you sitting down?"** before breaking the news:

- "Honey, I've just been held up and the son of a bitch ran away with all my money and credit cards!"
- "I'm pregnant and you are the father, obviously."
- "Remember that old coin you gave Jimmy?  It was valuable and he sold it for $300."
- "Mom, I got full scholarship to Harvard Medical School."
- "Mike and I got married in Vegas yesterday."
- "The doctor said she has cancer."
- "We'll have to cancel our trip to Hawaii. Mr. Clyne, my boss, says..."

**As we can see from the examples, it has more to do with "intense surprise" than with the news being good or bad.**

Comment: It might be helpful to note that the phrase is not used in circumstances most likely to lead to actual collapse—it would be somewhat callous to preface the news of a loved one's unexpected death this way, for example. In that case, you would give the news in person, so wouldn't need to ask about the person's state of seatedness, and would say something like "let's sit down" to get the person to sit. If you telegraph the bad news by saying "are you sitting down" or "you should sit" they might argue with you rather than sitting, thus leading to the dangerous situation you want to avoid.

Comment: It's more about preparing the person for shock than specifically being about bad news.  For example, the phrase would also be appropriate to prepare your spouse for news that you'd won the lottery.

Comment: @1006a  You're more than right.  I've edited.

Comment: Indeed, I recall the midwife telling me to sit down before she presented me with my newborn daughter (my wife was still under anaesthetic). She'd probably seen a few new dads crumble in the same circumstances. But the formulation "are you sitting down" also implies that the speaker doesn't know, which implies they are speaking on the phone.

Comment: @MichaelKay If you drop a newborn seated, s/he will probably land in your lap.  If you drop a newborn standing, there's a greater chance of injury.  Especially first-time new parents may not be all that familiar with the right way to hold a baby.  @ 1006a, sometimes there is such great physical distance that big news must be delivered over the phone.  @ Centaurus, the "I'm pregnant" news is probably a fit for the list regardless of who the father is.

Comment: @WBT Agreed, but in the case of something truly devastating, I suspect most news-breakers make an attempt to have some third-party on-scene before they break the news over the phone—I'm picturing police having to let someone know their child was killed or something, and likely contacting the local PD or a clergy member etc. to be on hand. People can have [literal heart failure from that kind of news](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/Conditions/More/Cardiomyopathy/Is-Broken-Heart-Syndrome-Real_UCM_448547_Article.jsp), so you don't want to give it over the phone when the person is alone.

Comment: Note that the question in OP, "*Can you sit down?*", does tend toward the negative.

Comment: @CarySwoveland   The person who gave Jimmy the coin is on welfare.  3,000 might give me a headache.  A measly US$ 30,000 would certainly make you, Mark Zuckerberg, Trump and Paris Hilton laugh.

Answer (score 7):

> When is the phrase, "Are you sitting down?" used,

When you are about to tell someone shocking news.

> and what does it exactly mean?

It means, "I'm about to tell you bad news."  It implies, "If you aren't now sitting, please sit down."
It can be taken literally, and probably should, to avoid risk of injury from fainting at the bad news, or jumping and hitting one's head.

For a literary-graphic illustration of exactly this, listen to [Ed Gavagan's Moth story "Golf Clubbing"](http://player.themoth.org/#/?actionType=ADD_AND_PLAY&storyId=1928) (7min 44sec) about (spoliers hidden)

> injuries sustained to him (if you faint easily, sit down for it), his drill-sergeant father on learning the news, and his mother (who was, fortunately, seated) on learning the news about his father.

Having heard this phrase for years, this story was the best illustration I'd heard of it.
(Adult content warning: not for the queasy; occasional uncensored obscenity.)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience as a native Russian speaker, this phrase is mostly used to break very good news, not the bad news.

Answer (score -1):

The same and similar phrases are used when telling stories to a group of small children. *"Are you sitting down? Then I'll begin."* or *"Are you sitting comfortably? Then I'll begin."* These have the same idea of being prepared for something, but for children it tries to avoid them fidgeting or disturbing others as the story begins and so missing the beginning. The "comfortably" version was used on the children's radio program [Listen with Mother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listen_with_Mother).